# Can't use @Async in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous

I want to use spring boot's Asynchronous mechanism, here is my code.

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

    private static final int MAX_POOL_SIZE = 50;

    private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = 20;

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setBeanName("taskExecutor");
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(MAX_POOL_SIZE);
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(CORE_POOL_SIZE);
        taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("async-task-thread-pool");
        taskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        taskExecutor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(60 * 10);
        taskExecutor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(
            (r, executor) -> log.warn("current thread pool is full, reject to invoke."));
        taskExecutor.initialize();
        return taskExecutor;
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return (ex, method, params) ->
        {
            log.error("invoke async method occurs error. method: {}, params: {}",
                method.getName(), JSON.toJSONString(params), ex);
            throw new RuntimeException();
        };
    }

}
```

And I add the @Async annotation on another class' method.

```
@Override
public Future<Result> getResult(String name);
```

But when I call the `getResult()` method, it report `No bean named 'taskExecutor' available: No matching Executor bean found for qualifier 'taskExecutor' - neither qualifier match nor bean name match!`.

And then I find this page:https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async. I follow this page's guide - remove the `@EnableAsync` annotation on `Application.class` and add to the `AsyncConfig.class`. But still got the same error message.It seems that `setBeanName()` method doesn't effect. Is my usage wrong?

By the way, I've read the api doc of `EnableAsync`, it writes

> Note: In the above example the {@code ThreadPoolTaskExecutor} is not a fully managed Spring bean. Add the {@code @Bean} annotation to the {@code getAsyncExecutor()} method
>
> if you want a fully managed bean. In such circumstances it is no longer necessary to
>   manually call the {@code executor.initialize()} method as this will be invoked
>   automatically when the bean is initialized.

What does the `not a fully managed Spring bean` mean? Which part of the bean not managed by Spring?

Comment: Do you mind to post your source repo?

Comment: Sorry the code is not allowed to expose.

Comment: You need to either change the name of the method which registers the bean as  `public Executor taskExecutor()` from `public Executor getAsyncExecutor()` or  name your bean as "taskExecutor" e.g. `@Bean(name = "taskExecutor") public Executor getAsyncExecutor()`

Answer (score 0):

Add a name to your bean annotation,  like `@Bean(name="taskExecutor")`. That should make your bean available under the name taskExecutor. By default it register a bean with name *methodName*. See here for reference [Spring Bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html)

Answer (score 0):

While the JavaBeans specification uses `get` (or `is`) prefixed to the name of a property for the getter method, Spring `@Bean` methods don't use that "translation" convention. The name of your executor bean is literally `getAsyncExecutor`; rename it to `taskExecutor`.

Comment: I made the AsyncConfigurer implements ApplicationContextAware interface. And use `Object getAsyncExecutor = applicationContext.getBean("getAsyncExecutor");` in the `setApplicationContext` method, but get no bean named getAsyncExecutor exception. And when I changed to use `String[] beanNamesForType = applicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(Executor.class);` but found the `beanNamesForType` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your `Application` is not a configuration class.

Put the `@EnableAsync` either on the class that has the
`@SpringBootApplciation` or on a class that is annotated with `@Configuration`.

Comment: I changed my code by refer to https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html. I've edited my question and my code, but still don't work.